# Swap Select drop down id

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, jqgrid

I am using a select drop down in the jqgrid.I need to swap the select drop down id's when the service call is successful.
I need to do like this ::

```
document.getElementById(lastRowId+"_selectId") = document.getElementById(actualId+"_selectId")
```

But I am getting an error alert like :: Left side of assignment is not a reference 
Can anybody provide a solution for this .

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code you are not swapping ids. `document.getElementById(lastRowId+"_selectId")` returns the element. You can directly set the ids like `document.getElementById(lastRowId+"_selectId").id = 'newid'`

try this:-

```
var id = lastRowId+"_selectId";
var id2= actualId+"_selectId";
var elem1 = document.getElementById(id);
var elem2 = document.getElementById(id2);
elem1.id =id2;
elem2.id =id ;
```